# Adding column to multiple identically formatted tables in Numbers

Tags: applescript, ms-office, automator, numbers, automation

I have a document in Number that contains many tables with the same format/columns but different content. I'd like to modify the format for all, adding a new, empty column in the same place with the same title, without having to edit each individual table.

An example: I'm tracking reading progress in multiple different books and would like to add a new field to track some additional data.

Is this feasible in Numbers, maybe with some AppleScript, or am I better off trying Excel with VBA?

I'd also be willing to try reorganizing my data in such a way that I don't need to do this, e.g., concatenating the tables vertically would probably work; I'd just like to know if there's a cleaner alternative as the separation into tables has made it simpler to organize the tables themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly. But, if all of the tables are on one sheet, and **all** of the tables need to get the same new column and the same column title, this will work.

[[image: Screenshot of Numbers document with three tables on the sheet]Screenshot of Numbers document with three tables on the sheet, before running the script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHbxP.png)

[[image: Screenshot of Numbers document with three tables on the sheet, column added and titled]Screenshot of Numbers document with three tables on the sheet, with column added and titled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAZV5.png)

Here is the AppleScript that adds the column and names it.

```
tell application "Numbers"
    set theTables to every table of active sheet of document 1
    repeat with aTable in theTables
        set myColumn to add column before column "B" of aTable
        set value of first cell of myColumn to "Birthplace"
    end repeat
end tell
```

A few notes-- you can add a column "before" or "after." Also, you can refer to a column by the letter atop the column, as I did here, but you can also refer to a column by the label in the Header row. In this case, that would be Column "Month".